# Variable value got changed unexpectedly in nodeJS

Tags: node.js

```
let fulfillmentMessages = []
let multipleRides = formats.text_message
multipleRides.payload.data.text = predefined_responses.intent_report_lost_credential_confirmation_yes.case_ids.response

console.log("Multiple rides Message")
console.log(JSON.stringify(multipleRides))

let noRides = formats.text_message;
noRides.payload.data.text = predefined_responses.intent_report_lost_credential_confirmation_yes_2.response;

console.log("Multiple rides Message after")
console.log(JSON.stringify(multipleRides))

fulfillmentMessages.push(multipleRides)
fulfillmentMessages.push(noRides)

console.log("Going to send these messages")
console.log(JSON.stringify(fulfillmentMessages))
```

After this code executes multipleRides and noRides have same values in it and array contains the same value twice. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that both variables, `multipleRides` and `noRides`, are referencing the same object, `formats.text_message` and thus, `multipleRides.payload.data` is the same object as `noRides.payload.data`. For that reason, the value stored in `multipleRides.payload.data.text` is overwritten by the assignment to `noRides.payload.data.text`. In JavaScript objects are copied by reference and not by value. You will need to do a deep clone of `formats.text_message`. A shallow copy wont be enough, due to how deep that `text` is.

[This article](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-clone-javascript-object/) will give you some hints for doing a deep clone. My advice is to **use lodash**, the code will be:

```js
const _ = require('lodash')

let fulfillmentMessages = []
let multipleRides = _.cloneDeep(formats.text_message)
multipleRides.payload.data.text = predefined_responses.intent_report_lost_credential_confirmation_yes.case_ids.response

console.log("Multiple rides Message")
console.log(JSON.stringify(multipleRides))

let noRides = _.cloneDeep(formats.text_message);
noRides.payload.data.text = predefined_responses.intent_report_lost_credential_confirmation_yes_2.response;

console.log("Multiple rides Message after")
console.log(JSON.stringify(multipleRides))

fulfillmentMessages.push(multipleRides)
fulfillmentMessages.push(noRides)

console.log("Going to send these messages")
console.log(JSON.stringify(fulfillmentMessages))
```

You could also use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(formats.text_message))`

I hope this helps!

Comment: That works, thanks a lot for your timely response. It was really a life saver